# Inline-videos don't play when direct URLs are pasted into URL bar in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, html5-video

If I link from another page in my site, they play. They look like this:

```
<video playsinline autoplay loop class="vf-video">
    <source src="/assets/video/the-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

When I paste in the URL and hit enter, they do not play. I even added this jQuery in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("video[autoplay]").each(function () {
        console.log(this);
        this.play();
    });
}, 3000);
```

Still will not play. They play fine in FireFox. Using latest Google Chrome on OS X.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking. What is a video URL page?

Comment: videos can only autoplay in chrome as a result of user-action, like a click. pasting a url is not a user-action.

Comment: Ah, so the click from the previous page would be considered the user interaction for the target page in order to start the video. No workaround?

Comment: if they work but simply don't auto-play, afaik, there's nothing you can do to force a play. the "click authentication" persisting across page loads is relatively new thing; don't be surprised if the behavior changes in chrome or other browsers in the future.

Comment: I just added the 'muted' attribute, as suggested by a colleague. They autoplay now.

Comment: nice to know, thanks for the follow-up; i'll keep it in mind. at first i thought you were loading the video url as the tab url, which should work obviously, unless the server discriminates against the different request params of a video tag vs a tab, sorry for the mixup...

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For video elements without sound disabled, they wont play without a user interaction. A click from a previous page is apparently considered a user interaction that should allow video to play. For my example, I just had to add the 'muted' to meet this criteria so the video would autoplay.